# What is causing these sharp protrusions when beveling?

Tags: bevel

I am trying to bevel a face and keep getting these sharp points, which seem like floating vertices or something. I have tried dissolving extra vertices and faces that might be overlapping, but no avail. Everything else seems to be working fine, it's just these 2 weird points.
[image]

Comment: I haven't seen such thing, but try to check if there are not doubles (Merge by Distance) before beveling ... if does it make some difference ...

Comment: Inverted normals, I think

Comment: @lemon Normals look differently https://imgur.com/VsrqBQ5, but hard to say ... probably both cases results in that :) The line looks thicker in that place.

Comment: @vklidu, yes. But who knows here.

Comment: @vklidu, outer bevel ; ) https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOUSJ.gif

Comment: @lemon What a cool thing :) +1